# How to start socket server (server.js) on Cpanel without npm start

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, angular6, cpanel

I have tried to use socket.io & socket.io-client in an Angular-6 application.

For that I have created an **server.js** file in my root directory. **server.js** file is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/myApp')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/myApp/index.html'));
});

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('New user connected');

socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('User disconnected');
});
});


server.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

In my package.json file I also changed ***"start":"ng serve" to "node server.js"***

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"       
  }
```

Now, On my local machine I tried command ng build and then npm start it works perfectly fine. it will show log message on terminal [image]

Now I want to host myApplication on web server (Cpanel) in which I copy files and paste it from dist folder but how can I start server.js file on my server

Answer (score 0):

This would depend if your web server simply serves static files (html, js, etc...) or actually runs an instance of linux to run your node server.

From my experience most free (webhost00, cpanel) etc, don't offer a linux instance but only a web server that host static files.

If you want to run a node server there are a lot of free options out there. Mainly `Azure`, `AWS`, `Heroku`, `GCP (google cloud)`, `Digital Ocean`.

The quickest free one in my opinion is [Heroku](https://heroku.com)